# Re: "a premise which maintains that…" Can a premise maintain?

Tags: word-usage, semantics

I was trying to define *false balance* [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_balance#:%7E:text=False%20balance%2C%20also%20bothsidesism%2C%20is,viewpoints%20than%20the%20evidence%20supports.&text=False%20balance%20has%20been%20cited%20as%20a%20cause%20of%20misinformation.) in my own words.

> False balance (aka bothsidesism): a media bias which perpetuates
> misinformation; a premise [which maintains] that two sides of an
> argument are somewhat balanced when, in fact, one side significantly outweighs
> the other.

I added "which maintains" (in brackets above) because it seemed to lack something, at the time, but I'm not sure that a [*premise*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/premise) can [*maintain*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/maintain) anything, based on their definitions (both Lexico).

By *premise,* I meant more of an idea than a statement; something more common, less academic:

> **premise**
>
> a statement or idea that you accept as true and use as a base for
> developing other ideas.
>
> [[Longman]](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/premise)

I have found "premise maintains" online, of course (about 2,980 results, including ones for *premise* meaning property). As suspected, the most popular usage I found was "based on the premise that" (about 25,500,000 results returned).

**Question:**
Is a "premise which maintains" (esp. in the given context) a correct usage, semantically?

---

BTW, I do believe that books can explore, and mountains can soar, and lamps can abhor… Not really that last one. Everything can't do everything.

---

What the heck is this about? Am I in an array now or what? (I'm 5 out of the 7 search results returned. That answers that. Not idiomatic.)

> How to create an array from single table data with parent and
> ...https://stackoverflow.com › questions › how-to-create-a... 21 hours
> ago — Re: "a premise which maintains that…" Can a premise maintain?
> Why are White Americans in the Southern region of the USA much more
> ...

---

Comment: I would think a premise can _claim_ something rather than _maintain_.

Comment: Like 'the claim that ...', 'the idea that ...' and 'the argument that ...', 'the premise that ...' is followed by a statement of a truth / suggested truth. ' ... misleading readers to believe that the evidence for and against a proposition / adopting a proposal is nearly balanced when this is a mishandling of the data available.'

Comment: Ahh, JJ... just joking. JK just kidding... Thanks for clearing up the mystery!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a pedantic peeve

Comment: @KannE, would you also object to 'the conclusion maintains', 'the book argues', 'the article defends the position'? Some people do object to all such formulations, arguing that only authors can maintain, argue, etc., but that is usually dismissed as a pedantic peeve. Or do you think that these formulations are OK, but that there is something about *premise* that makes it specially problematic to use it in this way?

Comment: @KannE: I'm always up for self-referential utterances - but would it be oxymoronic if I claimed that of late I like to alliterate a little rather than a lot? :)

Comment: The media bias is what's *maintaining the premise*. 'a media bias which perpetuates misinformation [to maintain a false premise] that two sides of an argument...'

Comment: That's literally *fake news* and colloquially the exact opposite, as that phrase is its own antithesis. When you say *False Balance*, I think of knock-off tennis shoes. It's called *spinning the narrative* and is not confined to news media or presidents. My nephew was told that the ice-cream truck only plays the music when it's out of ice-cream; calling the mother ship. Another term is *lies*. - What's wrong with the term *misinformation* ?

Comment: That's not a problem you can solve by inventing words.

Comment: @Mazura, Phil Sweet, the question is about whether a premise can ever be said to maintain something; the OP is not asking for a reformulation of the sentence about false balance, except in so far as it says that a premise maintains something.

Comment: to maintain something in this usage is merely to claim something.

Comment: *The premise maintains* is certainly used in academic writing. Are you looking only sample usage in dictionaries?

Comment: No, premises don’t maintain. A premise is already a “maintenance.” You wouldn’t say *the maintenance maintains* or *the argument argues* or  *the claim claims*.

Comment: @KannE: I don't understand. I thought I saw earlier that you'd actually placed a *bounty* on this question. Note that I'm not a mod, so I have no "special powers" here. And although I originally *closevoted* (for the reason as given), it needs 4 others to do the same before it would even be *closed* (and none at all have yet, so that probably ain't gonna happen! :). Anyway, per my comments under DaveClark's answer, in the event I eventually actually *learned* something myself from this question, so I'm now in two minds about my closevote anyway!

Comment: ...but if you're serious about wanting to delete it or dissociate yourself from it, I suggest you use the "flag" option to ask a mod to do something. They might want to make it a "Community Wiki" question rather than actually deleting it, since clearly many people want to upvote *answers* here, even if the overall reaction to the question is somewhat "ambivalent". I will just say I'm genuinely sorry if ***my*** posts here are part or all of the reason you're not happy.

Answer (score 12):

> Can a premise maintain? I'm not sure that a premise can maintain anything,

Yes, it most certainly can.

Consider

"The kettle boiled". Clearly kettles do not boil - but we all know that the meaning is "The water in the kettle boiled."

*A premise [which maintains]* is therefore an example of (probably) metonymy and perfectly valid, and means "The bloke who wrote the premise maintains..."

Comment: I don't think any metonymy is needed at all. Frankly, I don't see the objection to this construction at all.

Comment: Premises are at least sentences (if stated in language instead of logic). If you think sentences can maintain something, then so can premises. On the other hand, it's not at all clear what _maintain_ means with such a subject, aside from 'say' or 'mean', so it's hardly an important claim, true or false.

Comment: I don't think this is metonymy. Metonymy is when a part or attribute stands for the whole. A person's statement is not part of the person. And I don't think it means "The person who wrote the premise maintains." First, there need not be a particular person who wrote the premise, and second, a premise can assert something apart from the person who wrote it. For instance, the Ideal Gas Law is an approximation, and we should not take it as Clapeyron asserting that actual gasses follow it exactly.

Comment: @Acccumulation I did say "probably"  and the thing is that a premise must have an originator - it cannot come into being by itself. If we read it, then someone wrote it.

Comment: The OP is describing a situation  where general practice is to proceed as if a particular premise is true. It is quite possible for this to be the case without anyone formally articulating the premise.

Comment: @Acccumulation: *articulate* - to express distinctly. Someone has to do the expressing. If the premise is not expressed, then there is no premise...

Comment: People can express a premise through their actions without articulating it.

Comment: Mistaking language for thought is a fault line that philosophy has  mined for millennia. The Greeks figured if you didn't speak Greek, you couldn't think properly. Moderns are no better.

Comment: @JohnLawler, saying that this is a mistake is taking a philosophical position on a controversial issue. A developed, respectable body of philosophical thought/writing argues otherwise.

Comment: Nu, what's the matter with taking a position?

Comment: @JohnLawler, nothing whatsoever, as long as it is clear that the matter is one on which reasonable and thoughtful people continue to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Anthropomorphisms such as this are generally discouraged in academic works unless they are already in wide usage and do not cause confusion.  "These results suggest ..." is generally accepted.  "This premise maintains ..." who knows?

Comment: I've never been aware of any such constraint in formal texts.

Comment: @Kanne: After reading ***It results in ambiguity or misleading communication and thus should be avoided in APA style*** in one of your links above, I've made a "non-edit" to this answer so I could reverse my over-hasty downvote. DaveClark - *in principle* I think I should have only *cancelled* the downvote, and not converted it to an *upvote* unless and until you edit your text to include those links provided by Kanne as suggested. But I may not pass this way again, and you still *might* edit the links in (or someone else might do it for you, but not me at this time! :)

Comment: @KannE: I assumed nothing about the OP's work, merely stating the case in academia, as I myself understand it, as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by usage (Google Books), using *maintains* after *premise* appears to be acceptable. It's not ambiguous or confusing and provides an alternative to the usual verbs like *assert, say, affirm, hold, state*, etc. While I probably wouldn't have thought to use *maintains* after *premise*, when I read it in these examples, it doesn't strike me as too unusual or out of place. (In one of the works below I came across "this premise claims", which could be the subject of another ELU question.)

> ...it was found advisable to set up a premise in the nature of a
> definition of vocational education at the junior college level. This
> **premise maintains** that the expression *vocational education* refers to ... [*California Journal of Secondary Education*, vol.
> 16](https://www.google.com/books/edition/California_Journal_of_Secondary_Educatio/cY1ZAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22premise%20maintains%22&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&printsec=frontcover) (1941)

> The argument's **first premise maintains** that it is possible for an
> act to harm a person while they are alive even if the act has no
> effect on that person's conscious experience. The argument's **second
> premise maintains** that if it is possible for an act to harm a person
> while they are alive even if the act has no effect on that person's
> conscious experiences, then frustrating a person's desires is at least
> one way to harm a person. ... The argument's **third premise
> maintains** that if frustrating a person's desires is at least one to
> harm a person, then it is possible for an act to harm a person even if
> the act takes place after the person is dead.  [David Boonin; *Dead
> Wrong: The Ethics of Posthumous Harm*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dead_Wrong/XR6yDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover)

> The minor **premise maintains** that P does occur. [W. Clark et al.;
> *Principles of Comparative Politics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Principles_of_Comparative_Politics/2KFvJwi8_jwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA32&printsec=frontcover)

> This **premise maintains** two things. [Emanuel Rutten; *A Critical
> Assessment of Contemporary Cosmological Arguments*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Critical_Assessment_of_Contemporary_Co/8sHJD2fXDg4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA25&printsec=frontcover)

> ... but the strong version of the **premise maintains** that the net flow
> of environmental goods (e.g. food) and bads (e.g. pollution) across
> either... [D. Mollica and T. Campbell; *Sustainability*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sustainability/f0pBDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PT223&printsec=frontcover)

> The second **premise maintains** that if a proposition is
> epistemically justified a priori, then its justification depends on
> intuition. [Steven Hales; *Relativism and the Foundations of
> Philosophy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Relativism_and_the_Foundations_of_Philos/sINRmT4rZ5wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA29&printsec=frontcover)

> But then, if moral reasons are non-instrumental, as Joyce's **first
> premise maintains**, it is at best doubtful that moral reasons are
> authoritative, as Joyce's **second premise maintains.** [R. Joyce and
> S. Kirchen; *A World Without Values*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_World_Without_Values/Ac_KNUMVyrYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA148&printsec=frontcover)

> The **first premise** of the argument **maintains** that commonsense
> mental states like beliefs and desires can be viewed as... The
> **second premise maintains** that ... [D. Murphy and M. Bishop; *Stich and His Critics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Stich_and_His_Critics/I2wwQyiYlcIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA191&printsec=frontcover)

> Folk psychology, the **First Premise maintains,** underlies our
> everyday discourse about mental states and processes, and terms like
> "belief" and "desire" can be viewed as theoretical terms in this folk
> theory. [Stephen Stich; *Deconstructing the Mind*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Deconstructing_the_Mind/F7jaQXF7wkkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA4&printsec=frontcover)

> Blumer's **third premise maintains** that all meanings for individuals
> and groups "occur through a process of interpretation." [Doreen
> Anderson-Facile; *Dueling Identities: The Christian Biker*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dueling_Identities/qTF5FuVxgsIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA13&printsec=frontcover)

> This **premise maintains** that the private decision to authorize
> military force *does* impose risk ... [William Feldman; *Privatizing
> War: A Moral Theory*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Privatizing_War/XCtqDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premise%20maintains%22&pg=PA12&printsec=frontcover)